# Concatenating with List(Of String)

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, list

I am having a difficult time determining how to concatenate a simple string onto the end of each element. Any help appreciated. See sample code below:

```
Dim Results As New List(Of String)

Results.Add("Test1")
Results.Add("Test2")
Results.Add("Test3")

For Each item in Results
    item = item.ToString.Concat(item.ToString, " xx") '  <--- This won't work!
Next
```

Comment: **As an additional advice:** calling `ToString()` method of a `String` instance is pretty much useless. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Problem here is that you simply make the `item` variable point to a brand new `String` object.

Do this instead, it will do what you want:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Results.Count - 1
    Results(i) &= "xx"
Next
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want a more elegant yet still efficent solution, consider adding the following extension method somewhere in your code:

```
Namespace SomeNamespace
    <Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleName()> _
    Public Module SomeModule
        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
        Public Sub ForEachIndex(Of T)(ByVal collection As ICollection, ByVal action As Action(Of Integer))
            For i As Integer = 0 To collection.Count
                action(i)
            Next
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

From then on, if you import the `SomeNamespace` namespace in your code, you'll be able to do this.

```
Results.ForEachIndex(Sub(i) Results(i) &= "xx")
```

This way you are both elegant and efficient: no new list gets created and the old strings will be ready to get garbage collected right away.

Also, the newly created `ForEachIndex` extension will work with any `ICollection` implementation. ;)

Note that you could also make it a `IEnumerable` extension and use LINQ's `Count` extension to know how much elements you have. This will cover more scenarios but in some your mileage may start to vary. Remember that an `IEnumerable` instance *may* represent an uncompiled sequence of elements.

Comment: I used this method within the For Each block, and am now getting: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Is there anyway around this issue?

Comment: @user2643607 Don't use `For Each` use `for` as in the answer.

Comment: @user2643607 can you show your new code? It is unclear how you could possibly have ended up with such an issue.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ can help you:

```
Results = Results.Select(Function(x) x & "xx").ToList
```

Comment: This works of course but it will mean having two lists at some point, which might be an issue if the original list is huge. Still, +1 for short syntax.

Comment: This would create a new array, any references to the old would not get the applied changes.

Comment: @Magnus Right, but that's still two lists of strings loaded in memory. ;)

Comment: +1.  Much prefer using LINQ to a for-loop with indexes.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin But creating a new List is not the same as modifying an existing.

Comment: @Magnus: No, string references should be different. Because when strings are concatenated, it results in a new string being created (strings are always immutable). In your case you did not create any new string. Doing ToList to a list should do nothing, and this exactly what you are seeing. Try doing a `Select` and post back with results. The overhead is only on creating an additional list, but that is negligible. Code readability wins, IMHO.

Comment: @Crono: You may notice that my comment was a reply to Magnus, but he removed his comment, so mine probably does not make sense anymore. I am fine with your answer, otherwise I would comment right under it.

Answer (score 1):

Again, using LINQ:

```
Dim Results As New List(Of String)
Results.Add("Test1")
Results.Add("Test2")
Results.Add("Test3")

Dim result As String = Results.Aggregate(String.Empty, Function(currentItem, nextItem) currentItem & " xx " & nextItem)
```

Are you looking for something like this:
prints `Test1 xx Test2 xx Test3 xx`

EDIT:

I misunderstood what you were asking.  Neolisk has a correct answer.
Here are a few other ways to write it:

```
Result = Result.Select(Function(x) String.Format("{0} xx", x)).ToLisT()
```

Or

```
Result = (From x In Result
          Select x & " xx").ToList()
```

Or

```
Result = (From x In Result
          Select String.Format("{0} xx", x).ToList()
```

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to concatenate onto the elements in the Results List. So it would appear as:
    `(0) = "Test1 xx", etc`

Comment: Then, in that case, Neolisk has the right answer.  Crono also has the right answer, but Neolisk has a more elegant solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Why no use the Join function after converting your list to an array?

For example

dim newlist=yourlist.toarray

dim newstring=Join("yourstring",newlist)

Comment: Because the OP does not need a join, i.e. 3 lines must remain as 3 lines.

Comment: Then maybe i understood the question wrong. So he want to add a string to each of the list item right?

Comment: Yes, add a constant value to each of the list elements.